# Code a button that changes the underlying code of your program

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

Setup: A form with a text box, a button, and a list box. The list box has ~10 values that are added to it when the form loads.

I'm wondering if it is possible to write the code for the button so that, when pressed by the user, it would add whatever text is in the text box to the list box *and* change the code of the form load to add that text to the pre-existing listbox.items.add's that are in the code of the form load.

Comment: You need a data source, either a file or a database, etc, to save your information that is used in the list box.

Comment: So something like a text file that holds all of the items, and then append the latest item to the text file? So that the next time the form loads, the new text file is used?

Comment: That would work, but if you're planning on dealing with a lot of data it would be worth looking at a database as @LarsTech mentioned.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Make that comment an answer and you have yourself a checkmark! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment:

> You need a data source, either a file or a database, etc, to save your information that is used in the list box.

and as you commented:

> So something like a text file that holds all of the items, and then append the latest item to the text file? So that the next time the form loads, the new text file is used?

Yes, that is a viable solution.

If using files, make sure to use the `Environment.GetFolderPath(...)` as the path location.  You should almost never use your executable's path for storage location.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple example of what you ask for in code...

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   ListBox1.DataSource = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\NoobishDataSource.txt").Split(ControlChars.NewLine).ToList()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\NoobishDataSource.txt", System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Log\NoobishDataSource.txt") & _
                                ControlChars.NewLine & TextBox1.Text)
    ListBox1.DataSource = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\NoobishDataSource.txt").Split(ControlChars.NewLine).ToList()
End Sub
```

Where C:\NoobishDataSource.txt is...

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
```